# Torch fire always up regardless of handle direction

Tags: c#, unity, orientation

I have a prefab from some asset pulled into our project.  It is a simple torch.. handle and a particle system for the fire.  Works perfect if mounted on a wall and torch angle adjusted no problem.

Now the problem.  I attach the torch to the hand of a walking person, so the arm is not "fixed" and is in a more fluent movement environment.  How can I adjust this (C# scripts possible to attach too) so that the fire element is always in an upright burning position even if the arm/hand are in a somewhat swinging position.

I'm still a little early on in my gaming exposure, but 3+yrs in C#.net and OOP experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the velocity to "world space" and just provide a vertical velocity, the particle system will follow the hand orientation, but the particles emitted will always move upwards.